# SML: How to use greater than operator in polymorphic functions?

Tags: polymorphism, sml

In SML (specifically, I am using SML/NJ) I can write a simple polymorphic equality function. For example:

```
 fun mem (x, []) = false
    | mem (x, y::l) = (x=y) orelse mem (x, l);
```

But what if I want to do the same thing for another operator, such as the greater-than operator? For example, what if I want the following function to be able to accept Ints, Chars, and Strings?

```
 fun greater (x, []) = false
    | greater (x, y::l) = (x>y) orelse greater (x, l);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Edit: typo in greater function

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to use the `<` operator, no. The operator `<` is not truly polymorphic, but simply overloaded in a way that is not extensible in Standard ML. This is unlike `=` that does support overloading for new types. `=`'s type is `''a * ''a -> bool` and can be read as: *Given that `'a` is a type that can be compared for equality, `=` takes two values of such type and returns a value of type bool.* Naturally, not all polymorphic values can be compared for equality. Functions are an example thereof.

The notion of grouping some polymorphic values by a certain property (e.g. comparison for equality, or ordering) is called *type classes* in Haskell, and Standard ML's equality types is the only type class supported in Standard ML.

When you look at `<`'s type, it is either `int * int -> bool` or `string * string -> bool`, or something third, depending on the context. It would be neat if Standard ML supported e.g. `'''a` to mean *a polymorphic value that can be ordered*. But this notation gets tedious after the first two or three type classes and one wanders off and [does what Haskell does](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101).

The simplest alternative is to pass in an ordering function, `t * t -> order`, for some concrete type `t`, where `order` is the built-in type with values `LESS`, `EQUAL` and `GREATER` (slightly less fancy looking than `bool`, but nicer in the long run). When passing such comparison operators to all functions that need comparison of arbitrary types eventually becomes annoying, because you're doing this for a lot of types and a lot of functions, you could invent a signature,

```
signature ORDERABLE =
sig
    type t
    val compare : t * t -> order
end
```

and whenever you need to do something generic to things that can be ordered, e.g. put them into a binary tree, you can create a functor,

```
functor BinTree (SomeOrd : ORDERABLE) =
struct
    (* Let's export SomeOrd into this functor for convenience *)
    type t = SomeOrd.t
    val compare = SomeOrd.compare

    datatype tree = Leaf of t | Node of tree * t * tree

    val singleton = Leaf

    fun insert (x, Leaf) = Leaf x
      | insert (x, Node (l, y, r)) =
        case compare (x, y) of
            GREATER => Node (l, y, insert (x, r))
          | _       => Node (insert (x, l), y, r)

    fun member (x, Leaf y) = compare (x, y) = EQUAL
      | member (x, Node (l, y, r)) =
        case compare (x, y) of
            EQUAL   => true
          | LESS    => member (x, l)
          | GREATER => member (x, r)
end
```

which could be used like,

```
structure IntBinTree = BinTree(struct
                                   type t = int
                                   val compare = Int.compare
                               end)

val myTree = IntBinTree.insert(5, IntBinTree.insert(3, IntBinTree.singleton 4))
```

The point here is that inside the functor `BinTree`, all functions can take the order comparison operator `compare` for granted, so they don't have to pass them in as arguments. Lacking a polymorphic order comparison operator and the means to achieve custom overloading, I think those two options are the best Standard ML has to offer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your function is supposed to do, since it is the same as `mem` except for the name.

There are two ways:

1. If you just have an individual function, take the comparison operator as a parameter. For example

   ```
   fun qsort leq [] = []
     | qsort leq [x] = [x]
     | qsort leq (x::xs) =
       let
           val (ys, zs) = List.partition (fn y => leq (y, x)) xs
       in
           qsort leq ys @ [x] @ qsort leq zs
       end

   val l = qsort op<= [3, 4, 1, 9, 0]
   ```
2. If you dealing with more than just a couple of functions, you can use a *functor* to parameterise an entire module of definitions en-masse.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the function. I corrected it. Are there any ways to accomplish this without passing the operator as a parameter? I used the above as a simple example, but I have encountered function definitions that seem to suggest this is possible. For example in Appel's compiler book, he asks the reader to write a function a tree-search function with the following definition: `lookup: 'a tree * key -> 'a`. Unless I'm missing something (which is possible) either the > or < operator seems necessary in searching a tree.

Comment: @upgrayedd I'm pretty sure that you can't do what you want. The problem is that SML doesn't have anything like the Haskell type-class `Ord` that could function as the inferred type. Even though SML overloads `<` it doesn't have anything corresponding to its notion of equality types to go along with it.

Comment: @upgrayedd, a lookup function sounds like being part of a module implementing a map type. That would be a perfect example of something you want to use a functor for. Then the lookup function you get back would indeed have the signature you cite.